# Prevent udev / uevents looking up DVD at boot time

Tags: linux, boot, gentoo, udev

#### Problem:

Boot time delay caused by `udev`. Early after initscripts starts there is message saying `waiting for uevents to be processed` and causing delay on boot, it seems that udev is looking if there is disc in dvd tray. After udev has found disc, boot process continues normally.

#### Main question:

How to prevent udev dvd lookup at boot time?

Maybe there is some way to skip some udev related stuff and let boot process continue and then  later instruct udev to do stuff that may cause some delay (*delay in uevents, but not in main boot process, is acceptable after udev is initially loaded*).

Comment: Did you define any rules for udev?

Comment: @Nessuno no, I have not defined any rules. However there is two automagically generated configuration files under `rules.d`: `70-persistent-cd.rules` and `70-persistent-net.rules` and it seems that `*cd.rules` is just for `/dev` symlinks.

Comment: Ok then define a rule. Create `/etc/udev/rules.d/90-hide.rules`
The content should look like:
`KERNEL=="sr0",SUBSYSTEM="block",OPTIONS==”ignore_device”`
Be sure you check the device attributes first:
`udevadm info --name=/dev/dvd1 --attribute-walk`

Comment: @Nessuno does not make any change, I believe that correct way to define options is `OPTIONS="ignore_device"` (_one = instead of two for assignment_) so tried also that. I've also tried to get selector from existing udev symlink helper rules, it seems that nothing changed and I believe that device selector for rule is correct (_it works well for symlinks_).